# PInvoke a struct pointer to get the data

Tags: c#, pinvoke, marshalling, dllimport

C code:

```
// Device description structure
struct DeviceInfo
{
  unsigned short deviceID;
  unsigned short productID;
  unsigned short versionNumber;
  wchar_t* deviceName;
}; 

void __cdecl GetAttachedDevices(
  int* count,
  DeviceInfo* deviceInfoList
);
```

and PInvoke C# code to work with this C DLL:

```
    public struct DeviceInfo
    {
        public ushort deviceID;
        public ushort productID;
        public ushort versionNumber;
        public IntPtr deviceName;
    }; 

    [DllImport("Native.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern void GetAttachedDevices(ref int count, ref DeviceInfo deviceInfoList);
```

When I use this C# code:

```
    int count = 0;
    DeviceInfo dev = new DeviceInfo();

    GetAttachedDevices(ref count, ref dev);
```

I only get one device info in *dev* (when there are 2 devices in *count*).

What should I do to get all devices data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to allocate and pass an array. Declare the function like this:

```
[DllImport("Native.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void GetAttachedDevices(
    ref int count, 
    [In, Out] DeviceInfo[] deviceInfoList
);
```

Call it like this:

```
int count = 16; // not sure how you are expected to come up with this value
DeviceInfo[] dev = new DeviceInfo[count];

GetAttachedDevices(ref count, dev);
```

How to allocate the array? Perhaps the function allows you to pass a null pointer for the array to obtain the required size. In which case you have:

```
int count = 0;
GetAttachedDevices(ref count, null);
DeviceInfo[] dev = new DeviceInfo[count];
GetAttachedDevices(ref count, dev);
```

You'll be able to work out these details from the C code, or its documentation.

Answer (score 1):

GetAttachedDevices likely expects an array, so you should modify your second argument.

The problem is: is this array allocated by GetAttachedDevices (and then who should destroy it?), or does it expect you to provide the array?

And if the latter, how does it handle the case where your provided array is not large enough? Does it copy the first N devices to the array and return the total needed count, bigger than array length, expecting you to reinvoke GetAttachedDevices with a bigger array?

Comment: It expects to provide the array. If it's not large enough it gives just the given number of results. And yes, I can reinvoke with bigger array. Thanks for help!